# Stored procedure with transaction giving me error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

Can some one tell me why the following stored procedure is giving me an error -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(emailA varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE a  INT;
 DECLARE f_id BIGINT;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception sqlwarning 
BEGIN    
  SET a = 1;
END; 

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1072
BEGIN       
     CALL log_error(1072,'test');
END;   

SELECT id  INTO f_id FROM user WHERE email = emailA;

END//
```

ERROR

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqlwarning BEGIN SET a = 1; END; DECLARE EXIT HANDLER F' at line 6

Comment: what is the error message generated?

Comment: I have updated my post with error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add comma

```
DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
```

- [**DECLARE ... HANDLER** Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html)

Comment: I have seen places where both are used --- http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/transaction-with-stored-procedure-in-mysql-server/

Answer (score 0):

if not solved yet..

Hope this works

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception   SET a = 1, sqlwarning  CALL log_error(1072,'test');